# Strict Markov's inequality

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. If $f$ is a non-negative measurable function and $a>0$, then we have Markov's inequality:
$$\mu\left( \{f\geqslant a\} \right)\leqslant \frac1a \int_X f\,d\mu.$$

In an exercise, I have to prove the same equality for $\mu(\{f>a\})$. Could someone verify my proof?

$$\mu(\{f>a \})=\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}\left\{f\geqslant a+\tfrac1n \right\}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu\left(\left\{f\geqslant a+\tfrac1n \right\}\right).$$

Well, for all $n\geqslant 1$, we have Markov's inequality from above, so when we take the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ on both sides, we obtain
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu\left(\left\{f\geqslant a+\tfrac1n \right\}\right)\leqslant \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{a+\frac1n}\int_X f\,d\mu=\frac{1}{a}\int_X f\,d\mu.$$

Comment: It seems perfectly correct to me.

Comment: Looks fine, but doesn't it also follow from $\mu(\{f>a\})\leq \mu(\{f\geq a\})$ and then applying the regular Markov's inequality?