# Question on Equality of measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a Lebesgue measure space. If $f$ is a non-negative measurable function and $a>0$.

I am trying to prove a result relating to Strict $">"$ Markov's inequality  and I need one of these identities to be true assuming that $ a >1$ and $\mu(\{x \in \mathbb{R} |f > a-1 \}) < \infty$

$$1. \quad \mu(\{x \in \mathbb{R} |f \ge a \})=\mu\left(\bigcap_{n\geqslant 1}\left\{x \in \mathbb{R} |f > a-\tfrac1n \right\}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu\left(\left\{x \in \mathbb{R} |f > a-\tfrac1n \right\}\right)$$

$$2. \quad \mu(\{x \in \mathbb{R} |f \ge a \}) \le\mu\left(\bigcap_{n\geqslant 1}\left\{x \in \mathbb{R} |f > a-\tfrac1n \right\}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu\left(\left\{x \in \mathbb{R} |f > a-\tfrac1n \right\}\right) ,\text{and we have that "=" in both cases by continuity of measures from above}$$

If one of these quantities are true then I am done. I know there are variations of Markov's inequality with $ \ge $ that works but I do not want to use it. Could anyone tell me if any of these is true? or perhaps one that bounds $ \mu(\{x \in \mathbb{R} |f \ge a \}).$

I am trying to do something related to this [Strict Markov Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3404404/strict-markovs-inequality)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second inequality is always true just because it is true for any $n$, so it is true when you pass to the limit.

To get the first inequality, I think you can use Lebesgue dominated convergence Theorem for the sequence of functions $g_n = \mathbf{1}_{\{f>a-1/n\}}$ which is dominated by $g_1$ which is integrable by your assumption, and it converges pointwise.
(To see why it converges pointwise, remark that if it false, then it means there exists $x$ such that $g_n(x) = 1$ for every $n$ but $\mathbf{1}_{\{f≥a\}} = 0$. This implies that $f(x)<a$ and $f>a-1/n$ for every $n$, which is absurd).